# C Max Numbers In An Array Algorithm

Tags: c, algorithm

So, I'm just working on C code, particularly a function which accepts 3 arguments: an array, the size of the array, and the number of max elements you want returned.

Here's my code:

```
int* findMaxElements(int base_array[],int size_of_base_array, int number_of_elements_to_find);

int main( void )
{

    printf("Find Max Values in an Array\n\n");

    // Set up array

    int kinch[6] = {1,2,3,4,5,6};

    // Pass to function and get a pointer to new array filled with only the max elements

    int *given = findMaxElements(kinch,6,3);

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        printf("\nMax Value = %d\n", *(given + i));
    }
    return 0;

}

int* findMaxElements(int base_array[],int size_of_base_array, int number_of_elements_to_find)
{

    // Set up all initial variables

    int i,k,c,position;
    int maximum = 0;



    int returnArray[100];

    /*Actual Algorythm */

    for(i = 0; i < number_of_elements_to_find; i++)
    {

        // Get the max value in the base array

        for(k = 0; k < size_of_base_array; k++)
        {
            if(base_array[k] > maximum)
            {
                maximum = base_array[k];
            }
        }

        // Find the position of the max value

        for(position = 0; position < size_of_base_array; position++)
        {

            if(base_array[position] == maximum)
            {
                break;
            }

        }

        // Delete the maximum value from the array and shift everything

        for(c = position - 1; c < size_of_base_array - 1; c++)
        {
            base_array[c] = base_array[c+1];
        }

        // Reduce the size of the array

        size_of_base_array -= 1;

        // Push max value into return array

        returnArray[i] = maximum;

        // Reset max value

        maximum = 0;
    }

    return returnArray;

}
```

I have a feeling somewhere in the function something goes wrong.

```
// Set up array

    int kinch[6] = {1,2,3,4,5,6};

    // Pass to function and get a pointer to new array filled with only the max elements

    int *given = findMaxElements(kinch,6,3);

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        printf("\nMax Value = %d\n", *(given + i));
    }
```

This should output the numbers 6, 5, and 4, because they are the three largest in the array, however the output I get is always 6, 6, and 6. What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may not be your only problem, but in the lines

```
for(c = position - 1; c < size_of_base_array - 1; c++)
    {
        base_array[c] = base_array[c+1];
    }
```

You copy the element at `[c+1]` (which is the maximum) to `[c]` - so you keep finding the max...

You should start the loop with `c = position`, not `c = position - 1`.

And add keyword `static` in front of the array you use to store the return values, so they remain valid (this is one way to address the issue that Jonathan Leffler identified).

Comment: Array overflow is also a problem.  I would recommend passing in an array to receive the return values.  Using a `static` array is certainly a one-word change solution that 'works', but it means that you prevent the code from being re-entrant.  Only one call can be in progress at a time, and the latest call 'wins'.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler you are right. The allocation of an array of 100 elements "just to be on the safe side", and not checking that `number_of_elements_to_find` is less than 100, is a problem waiting to happen; I like the solution of having the space allocated by the calling routine.

Comment: Thanks guys. I modified the code and it now works. I also made an extra parameter to the function that will store the maximum values, and got rid of the allocation of 100 elements in the local array.

Comment: happy to help. It's good when you learn more than one thing from a single question... :-)

Answer (score 2):

One problem is that you are returning a pointer to a local variable, `returnArray`, in the function.  You can't do that reliably — it leads to undefined behaviour.

There may well be other problems too, but that's enough to be a show-stopper on its own.

Comment: +1 for finding that issue - if you don't mind, I included a solution to that issue with my "and your algorithm breaks here" answer (with reference to your answer). Not sure what the correct etiquette is for that. If I shouldn't have done that please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

The whole approach to find the Kth largest element is not efficient and elegant. I will suggest you to modify your algorithm, although with above suggestions it will work fine, but it's not good way to solve this problem.

I will suggest you to look into below link to modify your algorithm
http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/k-largestor-smallest-elements-in-an-array/

Comment: I agree this is not a great algorithm, but I think it's more a "learn to program" exercise than a "write efficient algorithm" exercise. Helpful link - I have bookmarked it!